# Keep number picker value when changing tab (fragments)

Tags: android, tabs, android-fragments, numberpicker

I've got 3 tabs (I'm working with fragments) and each fragment has differents number pickers... I have a problem, I' am on tab 1 and I set numberpicker's value to 25. Ok, when I go for example to tab 2 and afeter I come back to tab 1, the numberpicker's value changes to its default value, I mean, it doesn't keep the value a introduced before... I've solved this with an static class where I save all values, but I have to check that class each time I go from a tab to another one. Is there a different way to keep this values withouth using this static class??
I would appreciate any help. Thanxs a lot.
[image]

Comment: whenever any changes made to Date Picker, store value in some variable, whenever next time it initialized, initialize with old selected value.

Comment: isn't this what I'm doing now??

Comment: but are you storing it anywhere in any object?

Comment: I have a static class, so I store them like this: Static.variable = numberpicker.value; for example, and after I get the value like this: numberpicker.value = Static.variable;... I don't know if I'm explaining myself right.

Comment: Yes you are getting right. You can set number picker value by `serValue(value)` method.